# Need an alternative to java Robot class to use in Linux server

Tags: java, excel, linux, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

My test scenario is to open an excel macro file, use a shortcut key for macro button press, give the input file path and click on Enter.
This in turn returns data from the input file to the column in the excel macro for our comparison.

I have the java code for this with

```
 Desktop.getDesktop().open();
```

to open the file and Robot class to perform other actions.

This works fine with Windows. However, my requirement needs my scripts to be run on Linux 2.6.32-696.30.1.e16 .

I am facing issues with executing it in Linux server since I have used Robot class

Comment: How are you going to run Excel on a Linux server? Excel does not run on Linux.

Comment: @yole I tried generating excel sheets and also reading data from an excel file on Linux through Java codes. The only issue is I am not sure on how to extract data using the macro file. Which requires opening a .xlsm file explicitly, clicking on the macro button or using it's shortcut etc

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach seems to be based on mimicking what a human would do. Which is to say 'press the button that triggers the macro, and then copy the value it produces in some column somewhere'.

Why would you force a computer to do something in the way a human solves the problem?

Better approach:

- Use an API to generate, read, write an Excel document (or Google Sheets documents).
- Either use the API to directly ask the macro to execute, or (assuming this is not possible) simply reproduce the code in the macro so your code can generate the result.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on how to use the API to directly ask the macro to execute?